# What is the most effective way to start a riot in my prison?

Tags: prison-architect

For an achievement you need to stop a riot of 50 or more prisoners in your prison. However, I seem to be ineffective at pissing off my prisoners to a point where they riot.

So what would be the most effective way to make them rage to the point where they riot?

Comment: Upvote for title. ;-)

Comment: @Iszi hahaha :P

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When you want to make a selective prisoner riot:

1. Build (or use an existing) cell block with a few more than 50 prisoners (some might kill each other before you have an "official" riot going on)
2. Build (or pick) a canteen where you want the riot to happen.
3. Use micromanagement to make sure that the prisoners of the chosen block (and only them) use that canteen (Logistics -> Food Distribution)
4. Add solitary doors to the canteen (other doors work too, but when you want the riot to cause the least damage possible, you need to contain it until the guards and riot police are in position)
5. Wait until meal time. When all prisoners are in the canteen, order any guards to leave the canteen and then set all doors of the canteen to "Door Mode: Locked Shut".
6. Now just wait for about a day.

While the prisoners are locked in the canteen, they can't satisfy most of their needs (they won't even get more food because there is no path between kitchen and canteen) making them more and more angry. Sooner or later you will have a nice but contained riot on your hands.

Answer (score 11):

One easy way to make the prisoners really angry is to stop serving food. Food is a big part of how happy the prisoners are. That's why food is important if you don't want the prisoners to riot.

You can also take away all sleep time from the regime. This prevents them from sleeping and they will become more angry.

Just be careful so you don't start a riot you can't control. If you have a riot too long, you will lose the game.

Answer (score 5):

I've done it by accident when I cut off one of their needs, I had electric issues so my kitchen didn't operate for a few days, when everyone got hungry at the same time the riot that started quickly snowballed as everyone else were right on the edge of rioting themselves!

Answer (score 0):

I build a large holding cell, fill it with bunk beds.
Then, cut off water.
Lock the door, watch.
After maybe 12days, the inmates will go Nuts. I suggest having sniper towers outside the cell, then opening it.

Answer (score 0):

How to get a "YouPick!" Riot in 7 steps:

1. Make a large room, at least 25x25. The larger it is, the larger the riot. If you want large riots, use a large map. Make sure to have a double set of walls, guards doing rounds outside the room, and a airlock door system. (2 doors, preferably with remote doors.) Make it a dormitory.
2. Place a bunch of beds, toilets, and all a shower area in it so that the prisoners can be happy for a bit. Maybe even give them cable TV with HBO so they can watch Game of thrones.
3. Get a bunch of prisoners into the room. Make sure they are not upset. Take care of them. Feed them, dress them, send them off to smell the wall..
4. Remove all the beds, block off the shower, cafeteria (if you have one) and get rid of the toilets as well, make sure they are all trapped in the one big room. (DO NOT FORGET TO REMOVE HBO!)
5. Get riot guards at the entrance, and and other guards you can get. Have the doors locked shut.
6. Wait for a bit, maybe watch a episode of Game of Thrones while you wait. Drink some coffee while your at it.
7. When the riot starts, lock the doors open and say hello to hell, small or large depending on the size and how many prisoners you fit in it.

Notes/Suggestions: This will be very easy on sandbox, so I suggest you do it on sandbox. Get the supermax or max sec prisoners.